# How can I add double quotes? perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to add double quotes to a string or variables, I haven't found much about it, I know it's done through regular expressions.
For example I have this variable like this

```
my $ movie = "Spiderman";
```

or this way

```
my $ movie = "Lord of rings";
```

And I want it to look like this

```
$ movie = "" Spiderman "";
$ movie = "" Lord of rings "";
```

I would appreciate some clue or idea.

Comment: Do you actually need to modify preexisting strings, or are you just asking for a way to assign a value that contains quotes to a variable?

Comment: That doesn't need any regular expressions. Just escape them: `$movie = "\"Spiderman\"";` Or just use single quotes as there's nothing to interpolate anyways: `$movie = '"Spiderman"';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do this using regular expression but it's some strange wish...

```
$movie =~ s/(.*)/"$1"/;
```

Answer (score 5):

Escape them.

```
$movie = "\"Spiderman\"";
```

Alternatively, you could use a different delimiter.

```
$movie = qq{"Spiderman"};
```

Since you don't interpolate or use any escape sequence, you could also switch to a single-quoted string literal.

```
$movie = '"Spiderman"';
```

---

On the other hand, if you're trying to programmatically add quotes, you can use the following:

```
$movie = '"' . $movie . '"';
```

---

(Note that it's very odd to put a space after the `$`. I've-never-ever-seen-it-done level of odd.)